# What is the latest version of Python that works for Mac OS 10.4?

Tags: python, macos

What is the latest version of Python that works for Mac OS 10.4.11?

(This would be a version of Python 3 unless none of those work for that OS.)

When I looked on the Python website for Python 3, I saw references to the

Mac OSes 10.6 and 10.5, but not to Mac OS 10.4 or any earlier Mac OS.

Comment: I'd wager that building Python 3.3 latest from source Just Works on Mac 10.4. No pre-built installers are available beyond Python 2.7 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current versions of Python 3 and Python 2 can be made to work on OS X 10.4.11.  As you've noticed, as of Python 3.3 `python.org` no longer provides binary installers that support OS X 10.4.  However, there are [binary installers available for Python 3.2.x](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.2.5/) that do work on OS X 10.4 if you just want to try something with 3.2.5. It's not too difficult to build a current Python 3.3 or pre-release 3.4 on 10.4 from source assuming you don't need every standard library module, as there are a number of libraries that are either not provided with OS X or are very old on 10.4.  But if you are planning to do serious work with Python and/or will need to install third-party extension modules, I strongly suggest installing Python 3.3 (or 3.4) using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org).  The MacPorts project supports 10.4 on a best-effort basis; I have a current 10.4 MacPorts test system with Python 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4 installed so I know it works.  MacPorts will install current versions of all the necessary third-party libraries and there are also port files for hundreds of third-party Python packages.  It should save you lots of time and effort in the long run if you are going to be using 10.4 for a while.

Answer (score 0):

According to the website, the mac installers for python 3 do not support OSX 10.4. However, the programming language itself should work for all versions of python including 3.3 (the latest stable version). But you will have to compile it from the source yourself.

here's the link for the python 3.3 source:
http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.3/Python-3.3.3.tgz

the readme has the instructions for installing it once you unzip it.

you should also be able to install it using homebrew:
http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/02/04/how-to-install-python-3-and-pydev-on-osx

Hope that helps! I don't have OSX 10.4 so I was not able to test this. I'd be interested to know how it goes.